# Undefined symbol in shared library that should have been included?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am trying to create a shared library to call a c++ file in python with ctypes. I first compile the `.cc` file with

```
g++ -fPIC -O3 -Wall -Woverloaded-virtual -g -Wunused-parameter -I/path/to/dir   -c -o testfile.o testfile.cc
```

Then I build the shared library with

```
g++ -shared -o libtest.so testfile.o
```

I then run a python script containing the line

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/absolute/path/to/libtest.so")
```

And get the error

```
OSError: /absolute/path/to/libtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN7fastjet7contrib19UnnormalizedMeasureE
```

I know where this function `UnnormalizedMeasure` is defined, and I included its definition with the line

```
#include "path/to/MeasureDefinition.hh"
```

in `testfile.cc`, where that header file contains the reference to the `UnnormalizedMeasure` function. So I am not sure why the shared library is not able to find this definition?

Thank you!